# Como fazer atribuição de variáveis em massa no Python?

Tags: python

No PHP, para fazermos uma atribuição de variáveis "em massa" (declarás-la na mesma linha), podemos fazer utilizando a função `list`.

Exemplo:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Como fazer esse tipo de atribuição em massa no Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É bem parecido:

```
(a, b, c) = 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: não precisa do parênteses do lado esquerdo. (Por outrolado, dependendo da expressão, pode ser uma boa ter parênteses do lado direito)

Comment: Com poucas palavras...

Answer (score 6):

O conceito a que você se refere se chama **[unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)**.

Você pode utilizar um simples

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

Observe que tal conceito também serve para realizar o unpacking de vários tipos de sequência diferente, sejam tuplas (tal como implicitamente é o seu exemplo) ou mesmo listas. De fato, como em Python tudo é um objeto, você pode gerar a lista dinamicamente por uma função:

```
a, b, c = range(1, 4)
```

Só observe que o número de váriáveis a serem atribuídas *deve* ser igual ao número de elementos na sequência, ou será levantado um `ValueError`:

```
>>> a, b, c = range(1, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Este conceito também é muito útil na hora de passar argumentos para funções:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(range(3))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> print(*range(3))
0 1 2
```